# Scroll one div down and one up at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I created a site which is devided vertically into two columns (each one half of the screen). If I scroll down, having the cursor on any position on the site, the left column should behave normal and scroll down, at the same the right column should scroll up in the opposite direction.

I came along this question –  [Modify scroll direction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912393/2933265) – and tried to get a solution out of it, but I cant get it working.

This is what I tried: http://jsbin.com/UJEBohu/1/edit

Comment: before i try to answer, do u know css? javascript? jquery? ur jsbin seems to imply not that well... (how about `overflow:scroll`?)

Comment: I know of html and css, but I am not really familiar with javascript and jquery – so yes, my jsbin might be not really good.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a working solution, here: http://jsfiddle.net/QDUyR/1/

Put this in your `<body>` onload event and you should be set :)

```
// Add event listener for scrolling
$("#left").on("scroll", function () {
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($("#left").scrollTop()) * -1;
    console.log(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
    $("#right").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
})

//Move right column to bottom initially
$("#right").scrollTop($("#right").height())
//Get actual distance scrolled
var scrolledright = parseInt($("#right").scrollTop())
```

Edit: Updated to work no matter what height the div's have, as long as they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The different browsers all scroll a different amount each time you scroll.

Here's my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/WWK3E/5/) i have not tried it yet in safari.
I'm using a bind on the mouse wheel because Mozilla's scroll event fires multiple times every time you scroll once.

First I check to see which browser we are using and setting how much each scroll will be for that browser. Then I calculate how much to move the right div based on the amount to scroll for each browser.

In the mouse wheel event I check to make sure the right div does not go to far below or above the screen.

I'm using event.originalEvent.detail to tell which direction the mouse wheel is going in mozilla, and in IE and Chrome I am using event.originalEvent.wheelDelta.

Below is the code.

```
 $(function()
 {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6)
    {
        //Firefox
        var eachScroll = 114;
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') + 7).split(' ')[0]) >= 15)
    { 
       //Chrome
      var eachScroll = 100;
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Version') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Version') + 8).split(' ')[0]) >= 5)
    {
        //Safari
    }
    else
    { 
         //IE
         var eachScroll = 94;
    }

          var windowHeight = $(window).height(); 
          var containerHeight = $("#container").height();
          var heightLeftover = containerHeight - windowHeight; // Actual amount left to scroll
          var totalScrolls = heightLeftover / eachScroll; // Total number of scrolls 
          totalScrolls = Math.ceil(totalScrolls); // Always round up
          var amountToScroll = ($("#right").height() - containerHeight) / totalScrolls; 
          // Amount that right div will move every time we scroll

          $(window).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){
            var top = $("#right").position().top;

              if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta) // Check if wheelDelta exists
              {
                if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta == - 120)
                { 
                    if(top < 2)
                     $("#right").css({top: top + amountToScroll});
                }
                else
                {
                     if(top > -2000)
                      $("#right").css({top: top - amountToScroll});
                }
             }
             else if(event.originalEvent.detail) // check if detail exists
             {
               if(event.originalEvent.detail == 3)
               {
                   if(top < 2)
                     $("#right").css({top: top + amountToScroll});
               }
               else
               {
                   if(top > -2000)
                     $("#right").css({top: top - amountToScroll});
               }
             }
          });
      });
```

Comment: Yes this is the direction I am looking for. The only problem now is if you reach the end of the page with scrolling, in Chrome and Safari the div on the left stops but the one on the right keeps on scrolling. How can I let stop the right one too ?

Comment: I tried it in chrome, IE and Mozilla and it stops at the bottom.  Can you post another fiddle or bin of what you have and I'll see if i can find whats causing it.

Comment: I've updated my post, each browsers scroll events scrolls a little different. I hope this helps.

Comment: Now for me the box on the right side is not scrolling correctly. In firefox for example it seems quite confused how to move. Do you have any other idea?