# Updating scrollTop before scroll listener is assigned triggers a scroll event

Tags: javascript

I am updating the `scrollTop` of an element right before I start listening for a scroll event.  However, the scroll event fires, even though it was added *after* the `scrollTop` was updated.

I noticed that if I wrapped the `.onscroll` assignment in a `setTimeout(..., 1);` it worked just fine.

Also note in the output, the `scrollTop` value in memory does not change, yet it triggers the event.

> starting out 0
>
> haven't added listener yet 100
>
> listener added 100
>
> scrolled 100

Can anyone explain why this works like this?  Using `setTimeout` or setting a flag seems hacky as a way to get around this; is there a better way?

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

console.log("starting out", div.scrollTop);
div.scrollTop = 100;

console.log("haven't added listener yet", div.scrollTop);
div.onscroll = function() {
  console.log('scrolled', div.scrollTop);
};
console.log("listener added", div.scrollTop);
```

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id mi sit amet tortor suscipit sagittis at id risus. Nullam ultricies nisi ac tortor ultrices porta. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam purus sapien, efficitur in risus non, cursus egestas lectus. Curabitur pharetra erat sapien, et malesuada neque mollis nec. Donec dolor lacus, pretium eu ipsum sit amet, placerat vehicula orci. Sed viverra metus id magna sodales, et condimentum urna sagittis. Donec a viverra urna. Pellentesque lacinia commodo ligula sed porttitor. Aliquam iaculis diam nec nibh congue congue. Nunc eget dapibus orci, ac tristique nunc. Mauris nisl tellus, posuere sed lectus sit amet, vulputate sollicitudin magna. Nullam porttitor leo bibendum, varius libero vitae, ultrices diam. Donec mauris nulla, egestas non nisi sit amet, ultricies laoreet sapien.</p> 
<p>Vivamus mollis placerat felis ut porta. Pellentesque pellentesque blandit leo, fermentum sollicitudin risus porta quis. Phasellus gravida justo nec mi accumsan, in euismod tortor venenatis. Donec porttitor consequat dui ac iaculis. Quisque scelerisque dictum risus, eu gravida nibh sodales in. Vivamus sit amet consectetur urna. Aliquam quis pretium turpis, non rhoncus lectus. Ut vel mi urna. Mauris interdum congue felis ut faucibus. Praesent nec lobortis enim. Vestibulum velit nisl, dapibus vulputate interdum vitae, sagittis a nisl.</p> 
<p>Donec consectetur justo a purus sodales, quis ultrices enim sodales. Sed fermentum congue enim vehicula volutpat. Proin pellentesque elit et dolor congue, in blandit tellus aliquet. Cras tincidunt metus lorem, et tincidunt arcu condimentum eget. Curabitur sed ipsum nec erat mollis volutpat eget eget purus. Nam nec eleifend est. Sed ut elit eget odio mollis dignissim vitae nec urna. In vel libero eget libero rutrum consectetur non eget dui. Proin dignissim convallis elit, id mollis metus sodales eget. Aliquam non iaculis justo. Aenean vel diam nibh. Nam euismod viverra ante, ac molestie sem. Donec cursus justo a sagittis iaculis. Sed at maximus lacus, sit amet gravida mauris. Curabitur non odio at ipsum consequat fermentum. Morbi vestibulum nec dui id tincidunt.</p> 
<p>Integer nec nunc ultricies, mattis leo sed, gravida enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc sed turpis sed nisi consequat faucibus. Fusce sagittis maximus luctus. Maecenas at tortor blandit, imperdiet ligula vel, vestibulum diam. Proin consequat sodales nisl, quis varius erat semper vitae. Etiam ac pretium lacus. Phasellus in vestibulum tellus, nec tempus dolor. Etiam fringilla convallis rhoncus. Sed id enim erat. Integer congue orci sapien, ac porttitor arcu pellentesque eget. Mauris eu rutrum urna. Donec ante eros, scelerisque id ipsum et, pulvinar dapibus erat.</p> 
<p>Fusce eget bibendum eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec finibus justo a neque hendrerit, imperdiet fringilla nibh tincidunt. Etiam consequat a erat fringilla volutpat. Proin porttitor nec sem non semper. Suspendisse sollicitudin erat eu urna gravida volutpat quis sit amet leo. Mauris luctus purus eget purus mattis semper. Curabitur ut ante fringilla, porta neque non, hendrerit diam. Morbi dignissim congue orci ac vestibulum. Vestibulum ipsum urna, faucibus nec venenatis eu, efficitur vitae massa. Suspendisse lectus lorem, molestie vel consequat eget, malesuada sed turpis. Curabitur sit amet ipsum et justo sollicitudin pretium. Praesent dignissim, mauris ut hendrerit egestas, massa orci cursus justo, non porta metus erat et velit. Curabitur vitae orci eu erat ultrices aliquet.</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it's because the browser doesn't do the actual scroll until the next frame. So the event listener is set before the scroll is even updated.

What you could do to avoid it is ignore the first scroll event.

```
var scrolled = false;

window.scrollTo(0, 100);

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(!scrolled) {
        scrolled = true;
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff...
});
```

---

**Edit to reflect OP's comment:**

I can't imagine why this would not work for you:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 100);

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(typeof window.scrollEventHasFired === "undefined") {
        window.scrollEventHasFired = true;
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff...
});
```

---

**Further edit, reflecting new information:**

Would this work for you? This enables multiple events to be set and also allows for the listener to be called outside of an event:
    var scrolled = [false],
        id = 0;

```
var listener = function(skipFirstExec, listenerId, args...) {
    if(skipFirstExec && !scrolled[listenerId]) {
        scrolled[listenerId] = true;
        return;
    }
    // Do stuff
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', listener.bind(thisArg, true, ++id));
scrolled[id] = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', listener.bind(thisArg, false, ++id)); // This one won't skip the scroll
scrolled[id] = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', listener.bind(thisArg, true, ++id));
scrolled[id] = false;

listener(false, 0, args...); // call listener outside of event
```

---

**Final edit:**

This worked for me, don't know why I didn't think of this earlier:

```
/**
 * requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller & Paul Irish et. al.
 * https://gist.github.com/1866474
 *
 * http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
 * http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating
**/

/*jshint asi: false, browser: true, curly: true, eqeqeq: true, forin: false, newcap: true, noempty: true, strict: true, undef: true */

(function( window ) {

  'use strict';

  var lastTime = 0;
  var prefixes = 'webkit moz ms o'.split(' ');
  // get unprefixed rAF and cAF, if present
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;
  var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame;
  // loop through vendor prefixes and get prefixed rAF and cAF
  var prefix;
  for( var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++ ) {
    if ( requestAnimationFrame && cancelAnimationFrame ) {
      break;
    }
    prefix = prefixes[i];
    requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame || window[ prefix + 'RequestAnimationFrame' ];
    cancelAnimationFrame  = cancelAnimationFrame  || window[ prefix + 'CancelAnimationFrame' ] ||
                              window[ prefix + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame' ];
  }

  // fallback to setTimeout and clearTimeout if either request/cancel is not supported
  if ( !requestAnimationFrame || !cancelAnimationFrame ) {
    requestAnimationFrame = function( callback, element ) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max( 0, 16 - ( currTime - lastTime ) );
      var id = window.setTimeout( function() {
        callback( currTime + timeToCall );
      }, timeToCall );
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };

    cancelAnimationFrame = function( id ) {
      window.clearTimeout( id );
    };
  }

  // put in global namespace
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
  window.cancelAnimationFrame = cancelAnimationFrame;

})( window );
(function() {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

    console.log("starting out", div.scrollTop);
    div.scrollTop = 100;

    console.log("haven't added listener yet", div.scrollTop);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        div.onscroll = function() {
          console.log('scrolled', div.scrollTop);
        };
        console.log("listener added", div.scrollTop);
    });
})();
```

Comment: This was a very simplified example; I'm doing something more complex and a simple flag won't cut it in that scenario.

Comment: your edit is the same thing; just checking undefined instead of false on a global variable...  The reason it won't work for me is that I have multiple things using (and firing) the same listener at different times; the flag could be true for some and not for others.  I can assign some sort of data attribute flag instead, but I'm looking for less of a hacky solution.  This seems like something that should be built into JS...

Comment: BTW, I did not test that code, so there may be typos, but it illustrates my point.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but it's still an array of flags.  I'm trying to find something built into JS that would make the code work in order, like a callback, or a way to force it to apply, not a way around it.

Comment: Hi, I see. Updated answer.

Comment: BTW, the polyfill is there for browser support, but my solution is inside the second self-executing function below the polyfill.

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) browser support is IE10+ and all modern browsers

Comment: @allicarn, hence the polyfill. I'd still recommend using the polyfill, as IE9 is still quite common.

Comment: Yup, understood. Just making a note for future readers of this answer :)