# Scrolling lag on mobile devices after applying modified scroll direction

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll, lag

I've created a simple function which is responsible for reversing scroll direction but it seems like the feature is cpu heavy which is causing the lag on mobile devices - my assumption.

At first, I thought that it's gotta be that way and there is nothing I can do to optimize it, until I discovered website with similar function but with no lag at all. I discovered this in this question: [Modify scroll direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912393/modify-scroll-direction)

Here is the link to the website from the question: http://buero-buero.org/

Apperently they are using this:

```
<script>
function crisscross() {
$('down-left').style.bottom = '-' + window.scrollY + 'px';
$('down-right').style.bottom = '-' + window.scrollY + 'px';
$('left').style.left = '-' + window.scrollY + 'px';
$('right').style.right = '-' + window.scrollY + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Here is how it looks like on my phone:

[image]

As you can see it is butter-smooth, even though I've reduced the fps to fit in 2MB limit for the gif.

My function looks like that:

```
$(".wrap-work-right").css("bottom", window.scrollY * -1);
```

In both cases, scroll direction is manipulated by changing `bottom` value - not only but lets focus on `bottom`.

Here is how my function looks like on my phone:

[image]

Left side works fine because it doesn't use any js. Right side where I apply the function, clearly can not keep up with calculating the `window.scrollY * -1`.

It might change, because I keep on testing different options but here is link to my website (test version): http://mateuszkusz.com/ — I am still working on it. Since I am a begginer, I can not guarantee it is going to work on all browsers.

Why is my version of reverse scroll direction so much slower? I was trying to replace gifs with mp4 and png files. I also tried to manipulate `translateY` instead of `bottom`:

```
var shiftValue = $(window).scrollTop() * 1 + 'px';
$('.wrap-work-right').css('transform', 'translateY(' + shiftValue + ')');
```

Other than that I've also cleared my js file leaving only one function to see if the cpu usage is lower but unfortunetaly the lag is still a thing. Maybe problem is on the server side?? I am using could hosting. Or maybe structure for my images is just too complicated?

I am trying to repair this for 2 days but I am out of ideas so I would be grateful for any hint.

**EDIT:** As na experiment I've removed connection between js file and index. I've decided to test plain javascript:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
document.getElementsByClassName("wrap-work-right")[0].style.bottom = '-' + window.scrollY + 'px';
}
</script>
```

It seems like it works better but only when gifs are out of view. I will have to do some more testing.

**EDIT:** Here is jsfiddle of my reverse scroll function (simplified version):

```js
$(window).on("scroll resize", function(){

  $(".right").css("bottom", window.scrollY * -1);

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.break-off {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%; 
}
.break-screen {
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
}
.break-shot {
  height: 16px;
}
.wrapp {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 48px); 
  left: 24px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  right: 0px;
}
.shot {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp absolute">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="break-off break-screen"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="break-off break-shot"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="break-off break-screen"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="right">
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="break-off break-shot"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="break-off break-screen"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In past I had only one wrapper with position fixed. I was using jquery to get height of the left container and then I was applying it to the body to be able to scroll but in this scenario I had left and right side lagging at once.

Comment: Can you create a minimum example on http://jsfiddle.net ? Also the first thing I would try is to do the js same as the other site and see if that solves it

Comment: I can, but please tell me, what should I include in this example? I've provided the code for the scroll function and link to my website with live version so I am not sure what should I present in jsfiddle.net. EDIT: I am not sure how to implement this js into my project. I was trying to but it didn't work at all. :(

Comment: Just use native js like you already done. It looked smooth to me, did you try your new js on your phone?

Comment: I've added jsfiddle with my reverse scrolling. Yeah I did try this. It looks smoother but only when gifs are out of the view so at the bottom of the page. When I scroll back up the lag is back. Gifs shouldn't be a problem because on buero website gifs are present and it works just fine. I am starting to think that maybe I used too many childrens to create hover effect on pictures? I will test it. Yesterday I thought that my phone is just being retarded but when I asked my bro to check out my website, the lag was there as well. :(

Comment: What if you replace the gif with just text? is it smooth? Just test that so you can nail down the cause

Comment: After a few hours of testing I can tell that basicly, all the multimedia are causing this function to lag. More complex multimedia = more lag. With text or images filled with one color there is 0 lag. Yet still, my files are like 10 -  300 KB. Buero on the other hand, uses images that are way heavier with additional animated gifs. How come, their page is not lagging at all? The only difference that I discovered is that they are using images 1:1, where I upload everything two times bigger for the retina displays. I will test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional day of research and testing I know for sure what causes my gallery to lag while scrolling the page on mobile device (only in landscape mode, when the gallery is split into two columns and right side uses js). Please, keep in mind that my phone is not the fastest device on the market, in fact I've used Nexus 4 for testing, so pretty old model.

To the point: Apparently there was a bug in Chrome (2012 - 2016) where the browser couldn't properly and dynamically handle **scaling down** high resolution images, resulting in massive lag while scrolling.

Source: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92812

I do not know if this bug still exist but I guess it's safe to assume that UX while scrolling will depend on the computing power of your device. I was able to confirm that, after uploading some random low resolution image to my website. The lag was no longer a thing. Just take a look:

[image]

As you can see, even fast scrolling is not lagging. I know I've used exact same image all over the page but while testing same image in high-rez, the scrolling lag was instantly noticeable.

Another argument is the fact that http://buero-buero.org/ is not fully responsive. They are using 1:1 images and no matter what, **the page won't scale them down**. That would explain why scrolling on buero is so much smoother, even though they are using more complex and heavier multimedia along with modified scroll direction.

This is the key: **scaling high-res images down**. Now look, I know that during my test with low res images, they were still scalling to fit the container, (because I didn't bother to calcutlate the size of an image to prevent the scalling) but the scale of a manipulation was much lower, allowing my stone-age phone to handle the scrolling properly.

The last thing of course is the javascript function (called on `window.onscroll` event) that only in combination with scaling high-rez images down, might generate scrolling lag - depending on the computing power of your device.

**SUMMARY:** It's not the modified scroll direction that is casuing the lag. It is the combination of the js and high-res images that were scaled down.

Since I want to use high-rez images, I guess I will just make my breakpoint trigger on 1024px so that people viewing my website on mobile devices will not experience scrolling lag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folling css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    html, body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
}
```